# Joomla:Why use JView/assignRef() instead of just assigning the value

Tags: php, joomla

I came across this question: [Whats is assignRef() function in joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855102/whats-is-assignref-function-in-joomla-2-5) when I tried to search for definition of this assignRef() function.

Upon reading the answers, I still have a question:
It seems to me this function is used to create a key for the object and assign a value to it, like

```
$this->assignRef('messages', $messages)
```

If that is right, then why don't just do $this->messages = $messages?

Answer (score 1):

I think these anwsers anwser your question.

[Whats is assignRef() function in joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855102/whats-is-assignref-function-in-joomla-2-5)

[Joomla 3 - What to use instead of assignRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883180/joomla-3-what-to-use-instead-of-assignref)

According to above answers it is a php related thing.

- Older version of Joomla(1.5) used a PHP version which is < PHP 5.2
- Newer version of Joomla(2.5) used a PHP version which is > PHP 5.2

In older version of php when you assign a variable like this

```
$this->messages= $messagesOrig;
```

php creates a copy of object **$messagesOrig** variable is referring and assign it to `$this->messages`.
Meaning any changes you are doing using **$this->messages** will not affect original object (the one **$messagesOrig** was referring).
So you have to use  **assignRef()** and you will be using/Editing the original object as **$messagesOrig** refering

```
$this->assignRef('messages', $messagesOrig)
```

In the newer version of php by default php assign a reference to orginal object.So you dont need to use **assignRef()**

**References:**

[Joomla 3 - What to use instead of assignRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883180/joomla-3-what-to-use-instead-of-assignref)

https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JView::assignRef

[PHP References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Answer (score 1):

`JView[Legacy]::assign()` and `JView[Legacy]::assignRef()` have been deprecated in Joomla!3 in favor for native PHP syntax.